# Android ConcurrentModificationException on Set

Tags: java, android, concurrency

I've read many of the SO questions regarding this issue but I cannot understand why I'm having a `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException`

In a class I have this:

```
private Set<RequestOrders> mRequests = new HashSet<>();
private final Object lock = new Object();
```

All operations on the `mRequest` object are surrounded by a synchronized statement like this:

```
public void handleOrder(RequestOrders order) {
    synchronized (lock) {
        if (!mRequests.contains(order)) {
            final sOrder = saveOrderOnDB(order);
            mRequests.add(sOrder);

            handleOrder(sOrder;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting the error in this:

```
void notifyOrder(int type) {
    if (!mPause) {
        synchronized (lock) {
            for (RequestOrders request : mRequests) { // Error here while iterating
                if (.....) {
                    redirectOrders(request);
                } else if (....) {
                    ......
                    startService(.....);
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        .....
    }
}
```

Any idea why? Should't the synchronized statements prevent concurrency problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your method calls to add / remove RequestOrders from the Set may be occurring while you are still iterating over the mRequest set. Therefore the size of the mRequest set is changing while you are still iterating which is causing the error. To overcome this you could either:

1 - Create a temporary set which holds all objects to be added to mRequest. Once you are finished looping over all objects in the mRequest set, add all objects in the temporary set to the mRequest set.

2- Use a concurrent HashMap.

Here is an example of how you could use the first approach:

```
private Set<RequestOrders> mRequests = new HashSet<>();
private Set<RequestOrders> backlog = new HashSet<>();

public void handleOrder(RequestOrders order) {
    synchronized (lock) {
        if (!mRequests.contains(order)) {
            final sOrder = saveOrderOnDB(order);
            backlog.add(sOrder);
            handleOrder(sOrder);
        }
    }
}

void notifyOrder(int type) {
    if (!mPause) {
        for (RequestOrders request : mRequests) { // Error here while iterating
            if (.....) {
                redirectOrders(request);
            } else if (....) {
                ......
                startService(.....);
            }
        }
        mRequests.addAll(backlog);
        backlog.clear();
    } else {
        .....
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Should I take any special care on removes `mRequests.remove(order);`?

Comment: Yes, any modifications to the Set which will result in the Set size changing, (remove or add) will need to be handled in a similar fashion. Good luck :)